# PHP Curl, Request data accept in a variable

Tags: php, curl

Hello I am having a very weird problem. I am writing this code to get the data from the [koncat](http://developer.kontakt.io/rest-api/stable/quickstart/) api

```
$url = 'https://api.kontakt.io/beacon/?device';
$privKey = 'key here';

$cURL = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);

curl_setopt($cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Api-Key: ".$privKey,
              "Accept: application/vnd.com.kontakt+json;version=5",
          "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));



$result = curl_exec($cURL);
```

The problem is Data is successfully printing on the screen but I don't know which variable here is printing out the data. I didn't use `echo` command in my code. If I print out the `result` variable it prints out only '1'  meaning success.

Comment: You need to set the curl option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The php documentation about `curl_exec` says that it will return true or fail on failure. `curl_exec` will also print the result directly into the output.

If you don't want that, you need to set the curl option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` to 1. This will tell `curl_exec` to return the result on sucess.

Documentation about `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER`:

```
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  TRUE to return the transfer as a string of the return value of curl_exec() instead of outputting it out directly.
```

More information:
http://php.net/curl_exec
http://php.net/curl_setopt